# field--field-this-field.tpl.php will not be used by Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have a field 'field_this_field' in my Drupal installation.

For this field I have a template 'field--field-this-field.tpl.php'. Also I copied the field.tpl.php into my tmplates folder.

I did this so many times with no problems because there's nothing special.

Is there anything I can check?

I also have a template for the node type which works. But not the field templates.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Don't understand what is the question here ? Actually, I do but that doesn't come out of your problem. Do you use Display Suite module in your project ? Any theme preprocessors in your theme or modules ?

Comment: I need to override the html output of a field. So I can use a template for the field. That's nothing special.

Now I see that absolutely no field template is working in this theme. All templates above (node, page, html) are working.

Does anyone know, what could be my problem?